# Modifiers with 好き

Tags: grammar

Can I use the modifier ちょっと with 好き？

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

You can also use 「すこし」 and 「やや」 for practically the same meaning.

In very informal speech, some people use 「ちょこっと」and 「ちょい」 as well.